# Create team from two wi-fi connections in Fedora 25

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, fedora

I have two wi-fi adapters and have access to two separated wi-fi networks. 
Nevertheless, I'm not able to bond them or create a team.
I've read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/206841/bonding-two-wifi-adapters) and also various manuals for Fedora, but didn't succeed.

Is it even possible? Could you please point me to the right direction?
Thanks a lot!

**Update - what I've tried**

I've tried using nmcli:

```
nmcli con add type team con-name Team1 ifname Team1;
nmcli con add type wifi con-name Team1-slave1 ifname wlan0 master Team1 ssid FirstNetwork;
nmcli con add type wifi con-name Team1-slave2 ifname wlp0s26u1u4 master Team1 ssid SecondNetwork;
nmcli con up Team1;
```

Then it shows: "*Connection successfully activated (master waiting for slaves) (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/19)*", which I considered working.

Then I tried to start the slaves with `nmcli con up Team1-slave1` which failed with "Failed to activate the connection : No suitable device found for this connection".
(The error is translated from Czech, so the wording might be slightly different in original.)

Comment: It would be my understanding that bonding is done for 2 NIC to reach 1 destination. You want to reach 2 destinations. What exactly is your goal? Do you mean to bridge them? Do you want the two networks to be visible/accessible to each other?

Comment: Actually, I want to combine them together (team, bond, whatever...) and by that increase the bandwidth. So that means that I want to reach 1 dest but faster. So it's just about the speed.

Comment: ...So you've done what, exactly, and what was the error given when it failed?

Comment: I've updated the original question since it was too long for the comment. Sorry for the delay btw. - time difference.

Comment: can you even bond wifi? I've only heard of ethernet being bonded, and even then its seriously seriously finicky

Comment: To be honest - I'm not sure. That's why I'm asking.
As of the ethernet - my understanding is that the ethernet teaming/bonding should be quite easy to handle...

Comment: You absolutely can bond wireless NICs. I am not familiar with nmcli used like this. The one that i know is in the link. Follow the process here (bond0 is used in place of Team1): https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/BondingInterfaces
I don't believe the ssid would/should be specified.

Answer (score 0):

The WiFi gateway devide has to be capable and authorized for bonding to occur. The gateway has to be capable and programmed to ACK/send flags (Plug & Play) for bonding to occur.

I suggest searching for networking standards that address the Plug & Play interfaces of public WiFi access points (maybe under 802.XX).

Comment: ssh, don't shout...